# How add Path Parameters to controller with SwashBuckle?

Tags: .net, .net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I'm documenting this for whoever needs it, possibly myself in the future.

I have a controller with route/path parameters as follows:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("project/{ownerName}/{projectName}")]
public class ProjectsController : ControllerBase {
    // ...
}
```

How can I set the `description` and `example` of these parameters, so they show up in Swagger UI (generated by Swashbuckle)?

It's not allowed to add `[SwaggerParameter(description: string)]` to Controllers, only methods.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved this problem by creating a custom Attribute `[ApiControllerParameter]` and a OperationFilter `ApiControllerParameterFilter` that fix the generated Swagger document.

The attribute assumes a `string` parameter, but you could adjust the code to suit your needs.

Usage:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("projects/{ownerName}/{projectName}")]
[ApiControllerParameter(name: "ownerName", example: "some-user", description: "name of user owning the project")]
[ApiControllerParameter(name: "projectName", example: "some-project")]
public class ProjectsController : ControllerBase {
    // ...
}
```

```cs
// Startup.cs
services.AddSwaggerGen(options => {
    options.SwaggerDoc("MyApplication", new OpenApiInfo {Title = "MyApplication", Version = "v1"});

    // Add the filter to your swagger configuration
    options.OperationFilter<SwaggerControllerParameterFilter>();
});
```

ApiControllerParameterAttribute:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Any;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class ApiControllerParameterAttribute : SwaggerParameterAttribute
{
    public readonly OpenApiParameter Parameter;

    public ApiControllerParameterAttribute(
        string name = null,
        string description = null,
        string example = null,
        bool required = true
    ) : base(description)
    {
        this.Parameter = new OpenApiParameter {
            Name = name,
            In = ParameterLocation.Path,
            Description = description,
            Required = required,
            Schema = new OpenApiSchema {
                Type = "string",
                Example = new OpenApiString(example)
            },
        };
    }
}
```

SwaggerControllerParameterFilter:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Any;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen;

public class SwaggerControllerParameterFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.MethodInfo.DeclaringType is null) return;

        var attributes = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(context.MethodInfo.DeclaringType,
                typeof(ApiControllerParameterAttribute))
            .Cast<ApiControllerParameterAttribute>();

        foreach (var attribute in attributes) {
            var previousParameter = operation.Parameters.First(p => p.Name == attribute.Parameter.Name);
            operation.Parameters.Remove(previousParameter);
            operation.Parameters.Add(attribute.Parameter);
        }
    }
}
```